# Prove that there is no integrable function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}[f(x)]^ndx=2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Prove that there is no integrable function $f(x) $ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}[f(x)]^ndx=2 \ \ \ \ (*)$$.

**My Attempt**
$[0,1]=E_1 \sqcup E_2 \sqcup E_3$ Where $E_1=\{ x \in [0,1] \ | \ f(x)>1 \}$, $E_2=\{ x \in [0,1] \ | \ f(x)<1 \}$ and $E_3=\{ x \in [0,1] \ | \ f(x)=1 \}$. then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}[f(x)]^ndx= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_{E_1}[f(x)]^ndx + \int_{E_2}[f(x)]^ndx + \int_{E_3}[f(x)]^ndx \right)$$
Define $G_n=[f(x)]^n$, on $E_1$ the sequence $\{G_n\}$ is increasing and therefore we can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem. On $E_2$ the seguence $\{f_1-G_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative functions, so again we're allowed to use MCT. Hence,$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}[f(x)]^ndx= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_{E_1}[f(x)]^ndx  -\int_{E_2}(f_1-[f(x)]^n-f_1 )dx + \int_{E_3}1 dx \right)= \left( \int_{E_1} \lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x)]^ndx  -\int_{E_2} \lim_{n \to \infty} (f_1-[f(x)]^n dx - \int_{E_2} f_1 dx + m_{E_3}\right) \ \ \ (**)$$ On $E_2$ we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x)]^n = 0$ but on $E_1$ the limit blows up , therefore for $(*)$ to hold we must have that $mE_1=0$, So in $(**)$ everything vanishes except $mE_3$ But $$mE_3 \leq m[0,1]=1<2$$ Which means that there is no such function.

**Is my reasoning correct ?**
If we replace $f\in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ instead of $f\in L^1[0,1]$, does a similar argument work again?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $f$ to be nonnegative, then your answer is correct. However, you need to specify what $f_1$ is, as this is not clear. You could take $f_1(x) = 1$.

Now you just need to reduce to the case of nonnegative $f$.

Your argument holds up in any case for nonnegative $f$, because the monotone convergence theorem is valid for measurable functions with values in $[0,+\infty]$.